# Какой он, гоблин?

Tags: лексика

**Кого могут назвать гоблином и насколько это слово распространено в живой речи и в литературе?**

**И какой он, гоблин?** Просто уродливый или имеющий определенную внешность? Или у него плохой характер и поэтому он неприятен окружающим?

А может быть, это синоним слова ***урод***? Хотя уродом у нас назовут и приличного человека, если он не похож на окружающих.

**Примеры из литературы:**

Сейчас я этого гоблина делитом и в баскет!

Из Жана получится отличный гоблин! У него и рост, и сложение, и выражение лица подходящие.

Вот уж кто настоящий гоблин. Ни капли грима не надо.

Он нахмурился и забубнил, как заправский гоблин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Много видел "гоблинов" в компьютерных играх, поверьте, они все разные. 
Собственно, Вики все исчерпывающе разъясняет.

> Внешность описывается по-разному, но достоверно одно, гоблины — одни
>   из самых уродливых созданий в европейской мифологии. Они
>   антропоморфны, но рост варьируется от фута до двух метров. Впрочем,
>   гоблины умеют превращаться в людей, но три элемента их внешности
>   остаются неизменными: длинные уши, страшные, похожие на кошачьи,
>   глаза, и длинные когти на руках. Уши гоблины прячут под шапку, когти —
>   в перчатки, а вот глаза им никак не скрыть, поэтому, по преданию,
>   узнать их можно по глазам.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B

Но тут, имхо, другое. "Гоблин", когда им называют человека (а иного сейчас представить трудно вyе специального контекста), из просто слова становится эпитетом. И тут уже на первый план план выходит не столько внешняя характеристика, сколько сущность... Сущность их в том что они похожи на людей, но внутри кардинально от них отличаются. И с людьми скорее враждуют. Вот поэтому, пусть и несколько парадоксально звучит, я бы взял в качестве наиболее близкого частичного синонима не "урод", а "гомункулюс", "нелюдь" или изобретенное Стругацкими "люден".

До пары к ним из западноевропейского пантеона страшилок можно вспомнить "тролля". Если вынести за скобки современное значение этого слова, то тролли - гоблинские братья по судьбе. Их тоже никто не видел - и все представляют по-разному. Отношения с троллями у человека несколько иные, чем с гоблинами, но в целом здесь тот же случай. Только вместо уродства - глупость и неуклюжесть. А в остальном тролли такие же "нелюди", как и гоблины.

Вот если вспоминать еще и эльфов, гномов, дворфов и прочую живность западноевропейских лесов и болот, то ситуация будет несколько иной. Все эти персонажи куда ближе к людям - и часто оказываются их союзниками. Их "нелюдями" ну никак не назовешь. И что удивительно, их внешний вид описан куда лучше и не так сильно отличается от источнику к источнику.

(++)

В связи с появлением вопросов уточнил по английской wiki в отношении гоблинов, гномов, дворфов, эльфов и троллей.

Все сказанное мной - в силе.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_(mythology)
(тут даже и говорить нечего, что это совершенно разные кричи)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll
Совершенно по-разному описывается тролль в представлениях разных этносов.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elf
Ну здесь тоже есть упоминания об отличиях в представлениях у разных этносов, но я, признаться, принципиальных среди них не заметил.

Ну и собственно гоблины.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goblin
Конечно, англоговорящие не знают слова "нелюдь" и тем более "люден", но в остальном картина вполне однозначная.

Comment: 1) "Люден" как эпитет скорее подошёл бы на роль антонима к "гоблину" как эпитету. И к "нелюдям" их можно было бы отнести разве что в каком-то противоположном смысле. 2) Вариативность внешности троллей вряд ли выше, чем у эльфов. 3) Никогда не слышал, чтобы под "дворфами" понимали что-то отличное от "гномов".

Comment: *Люден" как эпитет скорее подошёл бы на роль антонима к "гоблину"* -??? @grizzly, а почему?  Вы хотите сказать гоблины - люди??? *Никогда не слышал, чтобы под "дворфами" понимали что-то отличное от "гномов"*- ну это вы мало  в King's Bounty старый играли. И в Eye of the Beholder. Гномы (gnomes) - лесные жителели, Дворфы (dwarves) - горные. Возможно, вас спутало то, что в переводных текстах дворфы переводятся более привычным русскому уху "гномами".

Comment: *2) Вариативность внешности троллей вряд ли выше, чем у эльфов* - опять отсылаю к играм. Сравните троллля в КB и, например, в QfG первой.  Я сознательно беру старіе игры, поскольку в отношении новых нет уверенности, что их все знают.

Comment: По поводу "люденов". Я хочу сказать, что у Стругацких людены — это сверхлюди, результат дальнейшей эволюции. Приравнивать их к гоблинам немного странно. Что касается других мифических персонажей, то на них лучше смотреть не по игрушкам, а по мифологии. Но здесь я сейчас не готов искать источники (давно этим интересовался). Пусть просто в комментариях останется "особое мнение" :)

Comment: *Я хочу сказать, что у Стругацких людены это сверхлюди* - ))) Вас не смущает, что "люден" - точная анаграмма слова "нелюдь"? Вы очень поверхностно читаете, имхо. Там весь фокус, что сверхлюди - это уже не люди. В том и смысл всей ВГВ. И гоблины, если вспомнить европейский фольклор - как раз такие "людены". Приобретя некоторые сверхсвойства/сверхвозможности они перестали быть людьми.

Comment: В какой игрушке Вы этого набрались?! Вы лучше бы поискали, что говорили об этом сами Стругацкие. А "Homo Ludens" Вы тоже не читали, наверное?

Comment: *Но здесь я сейчас не готов искать источники* - А чем вас Вики не устраивает? Я не вижу причин исключать игрушки из числа "источников", мы же говори на темы о представлениях об этих кричах в разной этносреде. Но я с удовольствием пообщаюсь с вами и предметно по мифологии. Мне оно тоже в какой-то мере знакома.

Comment: *В какой игрушке Вы этого набрались?* - Вообще-то для того, чтобы понять что "люден" - анаграмма "нелюди" достаточно знать русский алфавит. А все остальное можно найти на любом сайте, посвященном творчеству АБС. Но вы, разумеется, можете оставаться при своем мнении, что сказанное люденом Логовенко о своем происхождении это все, что надо знать о них людям. Я не читал этот трактат, думаю, что и вы его не читали. Если бы АБС не вспомнили о нем в ВГВ, думаю, о нем бы вообще никто ничего в России не знал.

Comment: Хейзинга входит в топ-100 наиболее уважаемых мною людей — за его жизненную позицию. Поэтому я его читал (давно, правда). И ВГВ мы с Вами очень по-разному восприняли, значит. Ухожу от дальнейшего спора и простите, что вспылил.

Comment: *И ВГВ мы с Вами очень по-разному восприняли, значит.* - я бы с ражостью с вами пообщался на темы ВГВ (и Хейзинги), но здесь реально нет возможности.   *и простите, что вспылил* - без проблем, я даже не обратил внимания. ))) Думаю, я и сам грешен подобным. Мне главное, чтобы мысль была понятна у собеседника, а уж с какими чувствами он её выражает - это к посту не пришьешь.